# Is there a reason why the __all__ variable in __init__.py is defined as a list in Python documentation?

Tags: python, list, package, tuples, init

As one may read in the [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) - `__all__` variable is described as a list. Is there a reason (or does it even matter) for choosing this type over `tuple`? Both options work but `tuple` seems to be more valid as immutable type.

Comment: FYI, as you can see in [the reference](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement), `__all__` need not be a list, but must be a "*a sequence of strings*".